# How to rearrange image pixels so that color varies smoothly?

Tags: python, sorting, optimization, colors

I have a 2D array of RGB colors, so basically a 3D array of shape (Nrow x Ncol x 3). Initially, the array is effectively random, with the colors all mixed up. I am trying to rearrange the colors so that they smoothly vary from one color to the next, though I don't care where certain colors are. Basically, I would like the colors of the image on the right to be as "smooth" as possible. But I'm not sure of the most efficient way to do this...

[image: My initial "brute force" attempt]

Currently, I am randomly selecting 2 cells, switching them, and comparing the "color smoothness" of the initial and resulting arrays. If the new array is "smoother" than the original, keep the change. If not, revert the change. My metric for "color smoothness" is roughly as follows: For each RGB channel, take the differences between the pixels in the horizontal and vertical directions and sum those differences. Large differences between pixels would indicate that dissimilar colors are next to one another. The numbers in the image are the values of "smoothness".

This works OK for a small (<100) number of pixels, but still requires many thousands of iterations and still isn't perfect. For example, in the attached image the new array (on the right) *does* look smoother, but I feel like it could be better. There are many yellow and red pixels that could be closer to one another.

So what is a method to find the strictly ideal solution to this problem? Is it a sorting problem? Some kind of discrete optimization problem? Something else? I am working in Python and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like a sorting problem. Make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The obvious algorithm is to put the colors in a list and sort the values. Then fill the array starting with the first avlue in the top left corner and putting subsequent values in a diagonal line advancing towards the bottom right corner.

Comment: Also, this question is arguably off-topic for S.O. as it isn't asking for help fixing concrete code. It's an algorithm question. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on. Personally I'm not too hung up on this distinction (which is why I didn't downvote it or ask it be closed), but I know other people do care about off-topic questions and understand why.

Comment: Also, I find the lack of exposition explaining why this is a real world problem, rather than a programming test, a red flag. It is okay to ask for help with your homework but you should be honest about doing so. After reading this question multiple times this seems like a homework assignment question to me.

Comment: Not a homework problem, but a personal project. Trying to arrange a bunch of pictures in a pleasing way. Anyway, apologies if S.O. isn't the right place for this. Yes, it is an algorithm/technique question, but I've seen enough of that one here to assume it's a reasonable question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first define a notion of `smoothness`. Here, I defined it as the average of some `score` for each pixel in the image, where I defined the score as the average of the sum of the squared differences of the R, G and B values of that pixel to each of its (up to) eight neighboring pixels. Obviously, both the `smoothness` and `score` can be adapted.

Approaching this problem naively (i.e. via brute force search) is obviously a hopeless endeavor, as for an image of height `h` and width `w` there are `(h*w)!` permutations. Hence, some greedy algorithm that at each step increases the smoothness (or, at least does not decrease it) seems like the way to go.

Essentially, I explored two techniques, one of which being the same as you already are using (i.e. for a number of steps, selecting two random pixels and swapping them if the swap improves the smoothness, see `smoothen_randomly`, which uses `greedy_swap`), the other one being a sort of preprocessing step, namely ordering the pixels.

The function `preorder` sorts each row such that the `R` values of its pixels are ordered, then each column such that the `G` values of its pixels are ordered and then each diagonal such that its `B` values are ordered, for a specifiable `n` times. My thinking with this was that it would make the main smoothing algorithm less prone to have multiple (as opposed to only one) cluster for similar pixels, i.e. allow it to converge faster.

To demonstrate, I sampled a random RGB image of 20 by 20 pixels and then for each combination from a range of preordering steps (0, 1, 2 and 5) and a range of swapping steps (0, 500, 5000 and 50000) plotted the resulting image. I.e. the original image is in the upper left corner, the first row shows the effect of only applying preordering and no random swaps, and the first column shows the effect of only applying random swaps without preordering. The number atop each image corresponds to its smoothness (or rather, its "unsmoothness", in the sense that lower scores are more desirable).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import randint


def random_img(lb, ub):
    """ generates a random RGB image """
    h = randint(lb, ub)
    w = randint(lb, ub)
    img = randint(low=0, high=255, size=(h, w, 3))
    return img


def score(img, ij, p):
    """ mean squared distance of a pixel to its neighboring pixels """
    i, j = ij
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    s = []
    for x in (-1, 0, 1):
        for y in (-1, 0, 1):
            if (x, y) != (0, 0) and 0 <= i + x < h and 0 <= j + y < w:
                s.append(np.power(p - img[i+x][j+y], 2).sum())
    return np.mean(s)


def smoothness(img):
    """ mean score across all pixels """
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    scores = []
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            scores.append(score(img, (i, j), img[i, j]))
    return int(np.sqrt(np.mean(scores)))


def preorder(img, n):
    """ order R values along the vertical, G values along the horizontal and B values along the diagonal """
    img2 = np.copy(img)
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    for k in range(n):
        img2 = np.array([sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[0]) for arr in img2])
        img2 = np.array([sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[1]) for arr in img2.T]).T
        a = [(i, 0) for i in range(h-1, -1, -1)]
        b = [(0, j) for j in range(1, w, 1)]
        for (i, j) in a + b:
            rng = range(min(h-i, w-j))
            arr = [np.copy(img2[i + x, j + x]) for x in rng]
            for rgb, ofs in zip(sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[2]), rng):
                img2[i+ofs, j+ofs] = rgb
    return img2


def greedy_swap(img, ij1, ij2):
    """ swap two pixels iff the swap increases the smoothness """
    i1, j1 = ij1
    i2, j2 = ij2
    a = img[i1][j1].copy()
    b = img[i2][j2].copy()
    s1 = score(img, ij1, a)
    s2 = score(img, ij2, b)
    s1_2 = score(img, ij1, b)
    s2_2 = score(img, ij2, a)
    if s1_2 + s2_2 < s1 + s2:
        img[i1, j1] = b
        img[i2, j2] = a


def smoothen_randomly(img, n):
    """ swap two random pixels if swap improves score, for n steps """
    img2 = np.copy(img)
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    for k in range(n):
        i1 = randint(low=0, high=h)
        j1 = randint(low=0, high=w)
        i2 = randint(low=0, high=h)
        j2 = randint(low=0, high=w)
        greedy_swap(img2, (i1, j1), (i2, j2))
    return img2


img = random_img(20, 21)
n_preorders = [0, 1, 2, 4]
n_swaps = [0, 500, 5000, 50000]

figure, axes = plt.subplots(len(n_swaps), len(n_preorders), figsize=(10, 10))
for ax, x in zip(axes[:,0], n_swaps):
    ax.set_ylabel(f'{x}', fontsize=12)
for i, x1 in enumerate(n_preorders):
    for j, x2 in enumerate(n_swaps):
        img2 = smoothen_randomly(preorder(img, x1), x2)
        axes[j, i].imshow(img2)
        axes[j, i].set_xticks([])
        axes[j, i].set_yticks([])
        prefix = f'{x1}\n' if j == 0 else ''
        axes[j, i].set_title(prefix + f'{smoothness(img2)}')
plt.show()
```

[image: Smoothing]

There are many avenues that could be further explored that may lead to improved performance, such as

- playing around with the score function (e.g. what if non-squared differences are used)
- looking into pixel selection methods when considering swaps (e.g. deterministic instead of random)
- considering different approaches, such as clustering (where I would expect some difficulty to map the of clusters of pixels onto a 2d grid).

Comment: Looks promising. Another idea might be to first convert to ***Lab*** colourscape, which is more perceptually uniform, which would mean the distances between pixels is far more analgous to the differences our eyes perceive. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space

Comment: This does look good and is definitely more rigorous than my attempts. Though it looks like it runs into the same issue I was: multiple clusters of the same color.

Changing the colorspace would be a good idea as well!

Something else I played around with was ordering the image in 1D by the difference between red and blue in a pixel. Gives a decent result, but black/white/grey pixels complicate things. Maybe I should combine the two...